# JS innerHTML when uses a function types not what it is supposed to

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="number" id="first">
        <input type="number" id="second">
        <button id="butId">Максимум</button>
        <p id="out">
            123
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <script>        
    function min(a, b) {
        console.log('1');
        if (a>b) return b
        else return a;
    }
    butId.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       out.innerHTML=min(first,second);  
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

it supposed to show in `<p id='out'>` the minimal number of the two typed in. it shows

> [object HTMLInputElement]

instead of a number and i do not see any errors

Comment: `first` and `second` refer to the `<input>` elements.  You want to compare the _value_ from these elements.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Actually the `valueAsNumber`. See [Input value is a string instead of a number](/q/27849944/4642212). This is very unlikely to be intended as a lexicographic comparison.

Comment: totally forgot about it. Thanks a lot, post an answer ill accept it

Comment: There’s a built-in `Math.min`. Don’t rely on [elements with IDs becoming available as global properties](/q/3434278/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the actual *value* entered into each `<input>` element, not the element itself.

```
butId.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    out.innerHTML = min(+first.value, +second.value);
});
```

Note: The `+` before the variables converts them to ints.

Comment: _“converts them to ints”_ — No, it coerces the strings to numbers. Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).

Comment: I was trying to simplify my explanation when I said "converts them to ints."  Also, I use multiple languages so I sometimes forget what each ones calls primitive "number" values.

Comment: @SebastianSimon What's wrong with using the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) operator?  Why would I use `parseFloat` over `parseInt` on what I would assume is an "integer" input?  Also, I didn't know about `valueAsNumber`.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with unary `+`, but it can make code less readable. All I want is to encourage _considering_ the other options because they may be more readable or make more sense, but it comes down to preference in the end. I wouldn’t assume `<input type="number">` to be integer inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to find the minimum value of each element, as opposed to the number inside it. You instead want to use

`out.textContent = Math.min(first.valueAsNumber,second.valueAsNumber)`

Here, we are getting the `valueAsNumber` of each input box and performing our `min()` calculation on it. This takes the text inside the `input` box and converts it to a number. You may also notice the `Math.min`, JS has a `min` function built in, so you do not need to define your own function for it. Additionally, it's good practice to use `textContent` to prevent XSS injection.

[`Math.min()` - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

[`valueAsNumber` attribute - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: I’d use `textContent` instead of `innerText`.